# i am trying to search two strings in a line but command not identifying 2nd match and displaying the first match only

Tags: powershell, search

i am trying with below command but command not identifying 2nd match and displaying the first match only.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\myfolder\myfile.xml | Select-String '(FOLDER NAME="+([^"]+)).*?(SHARED="+([^"]+))' 
-AllMatches |
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
ForEach-Object { "$($_.Groups[1].Value), $($_.Groups[2].Value)" }
```

my file content is

```
FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="GOOD" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="Shared" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED"
```

the output coming is

```
FOLDER NAME="HELLO, HELLO
FOLDER NAME="GOOD, GOOD
FOLDER NAME="Shared, Shared
```

but the desired output will be

```
HELLO, NOTSHARED
GOOD, NOTSHARED
Shared, SHARED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the $_.Matches.Groups you will see your matches are in capture group 2 and 4

```
@'
FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="GOOD" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="Shared" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED"
'@ | Select-String '(FOLDER NAME="+([^"]+)).*?(SHARED="+([^"]+))' | foreach{$_.matches.groups}

Groups   : {0, 1, 2, 3...}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 68
Value    : FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 0
Length   : 18
Value    : FOLDER NAME="HELLO

Success  : True
Name     : 2
Captures : {2}
Index    : 13
Length   : 5
Value    : HELLO

Success  : True
Name     : 3
Captures : {3}
Index    : 51
Length   : 17
Value    : SHARED="NOTSHARED

Success  : True
Name     : 4
Captures : {4}
Index    : 59
Length   : 9
Value    : NOTSHARED
```

If you simply remove the extra parentheses then the capture groups will be what you are expecting.

```
@'
FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="GOOD" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="Shared" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED"
'@ | Select-String 'FOLDER NAME="+([^"]+).*?SHARED="+([^"]+)' | foreach{$_.matches.groups}

Groups   : {0, 1, 2}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 0
Length   : 68
Value    : FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED

Success  : True
Name     : 1
Captures : {1}
Index    : 13
Length   : 5
Value    : HELLO

Success  : True
Name     : 2
Captures : {2}
Index    : 59
Length   : 9
Value    : NOTSHARED
```

Now it should output the desired results.

```
@'
FOLDER NAME="HELLO" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="GOOD" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="NOTSHARED"
FOLDER NAME="Shared" GROUP="" OWNER="Administrator" SHARED="SHARED"
'@  | Select-String 'FOLDER NAME="+([^"]+).*?SHARED="+([^"]+)' -AllMatches |
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
ForEach-Object { "$($_.Groups[1].Value), $($_.Groups[2].Value)" }  

HELLO, NOTSHARED
GOOD, NOTSHARED
Shared, SHARED
```